# Group days of the week with same values in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, label, schedule

I have a service request with schedules for a shop in an array called "hoursArray" with this format:

```
"hours": [
      "00:00-23:59",
      "00:00-23:59",
      "00:00-21:59",
      "00:00-21:59",
      "00:00-22:59",
      "00:00-22:59",
      "00:00-23:59"
    ]
```

I show this information in an horizontal stack view that contains two verticals stack views, one with labels for the seven days of the week and another one with seven labels for the schedule for that day, I fill this labels with this function:

```
  func getSchedule(){
        scheduleLabel1.text = hoursArray[0] as? String
        scheduleLabel2.text = hoursArray[1] as? String
        scheduleLabel3.text = hoursArray[2] as? String
        scheduleLabel4.text = hoursArray[3] as? String
        scheduleLabel5.text = hoursArray[4] as? String
        scheduleLabel6.text = hoursArray[5] as? String
        scheduleLabel7.text = hoursArray[6] as? String
        dayLabel1.text = "Monday"
        dayLabel2.text = "Tuesday"
        dayLabel3.text = "Wednesday"
        dayLabel4.text = "Thursday"
        dayLabel5.text = "Friday"
        dayLabel6.text = "Saturday"
        dayLabel7.text = "Sunday"
    }
```

What I need is to group correlative days to show it when I have a response of the request with days with the same value, for example if Monday and Tuesday have the same value I will show "Monday - Tuesday" in day1Label.text and its schedule in scheduleLabel1.text, how could I do that?

Comment: Is this about how to group your data or how to handle a varying number of labels in the UI?

Comment: both, because I need first to handle my data and then I need to handle the number of labels and the values of names of the days grouping them

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is like this, first grouping the data by hour range:

```
let hourRanges = [
    "00:00-23:59",
    "00:00-23:59",
    "00:00-21:59",
    "00:00-21:59",
    "00:00-22:59",
    "00:00-22:59",
    "00:00-23:59"
]

let weekDays = [
    "Monday",
    "Tuesday",
    "Wednesday",
    "Thursday",
    "Friday",
    "Saturday",
    "Sunday",
]

struct WeekDaysHourRange {
    let hourRange: String
    var weekDays: [String]
}

var daysRanges: [WeekDaysHourRange] = []

// assuming both arrays have the same length, otherwise checks are needed    
var previousWeekDayRange: WeekDaysHourRange?
for i in 0...6 {
    let hourRange = hourRanges[i]
    let weekDay = weekDays[i]
    
    if previousWeekDayRange?.hourRange == hourRange {
        daysRanges[daysRanges.count - 1].weekDays.append(weekDay)
    } else {
        let newWeekDayRange = WeekDaysHourRange(hourRange: hourRange, weekDays: [weekDay])
        previousWeekDayRange = newWeekDayRange
        daysRanges.append(newWeekDayRange)
    }
}
```

To update the UI, I would create to arrays of UILabels, to allow populating the labels with a for loop easilly, like this:

```
let scheduleLabels: [UILabel] = [
    scheduleLabel1,
    scheduleLabel2,
    scheduleLabel3,
    scheduleLabel4,
    scheduleLabel5,
    scheduleLabel6,
    scheduleLabel7
]

let dayLabels: [UILabel] = [
    dayLabel1,
    dayLabel2,
    dayLabel3,
    dayLabel4,
    dayLabel5,
    dayLabel6,
    dayLabel7
]

daysRanges.enumerated().forEach { (i, weekDayHourRange) in
    var daysString: String
    if weekDayHourRange.weekDays.count == 1 {
        daysString = weekDayHourRange.weekDays.first!
    } else {
        daysString = "\(weekDayHourRange.weekDays.first!) - \(weekDayHourRange.weekDays.last!)"
    }
    
    dayLabels[i].text = daysString
    scheduleLabels[i].text = weekDayHourRange.hourRange
}
```

Following Joakim Danielson comment, and If you only need to create the view once and not updated it, you can create the views on the fly:

```
daysRanges.enumerated().forEach { (i, weekDayHourRange) in
    var daysString: String
    if weekDayHourRange.weekDays.count == 1 {
        daysString = weekDayHourRange.weekDays.first!
    } else {
        daysString = "\(weekDayHourRange.weekDays.first!) - \(weekDayHourRange.weekDays.last!)"
    }

    let dayLabel = UILabel()
    dayLabel.text = daysString
    
    let scheduleLabel = UILabel()
    scheduleLabel.text = weekDayHourRange.hourRange
    
    dayLabelsStackView.addArrangedSubview(dayLabel)
    scheduleLabelsStackView.addArrangedSubview(scheduleLabel)
}
```

This would output something like this:

```
"Monday - Tuesday - 00:00-23:59"
"Wednesday - Thursday - 00:00-21:59"
"Friday - Saturday - 00:00-22:59"
"Sunday - 00:00-23:59"
```

Comment: This was just a guideline on how to do it, but I'll update my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use following function to format

```
let hours = [
    "00:00-23:59",
    "00:00-23:59",
    "00:00-21:59",
    "00:00-21:59",
    "00:00-22:59",
    "00:00-22:59",
    "00:00-23:59"
]

let days = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]


func format() -> [(String, String)] {
    
    var temp: [(String, String)] = []
    for i in 0..<hours.count {
        temp.append((days[i], hours[i]))
    }
    
    var result: [(String, String)] = []
    
    var index = 0
    
    var dayStart: String?
    var dayEnd: String?
    var time: String?
    
    while index < temp.count {
        
        if dayStart == nil {
            dayStart = temp[index].0
            time = temp[index].1
        }
        
        if (index != temp.count - 1) && (temp[index].1 == temp[index+1].1)  {
            dayEnd = temp[index+1].0
            index += 1
        }
        else {
            if let start = dayStart, let tm = time {
                if let end = dayEnd {
                    result.append(("\(start)-\(end)", tm))
                    dayEnd = nil
                }
                else {
                    result.append((start, tm))
                }
                dayStart = nil
                time = nil
            }
            index += 1
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

From this you will get formatted result and you can then pass these as an input to TableView or IBOutletCollection. Using static labels for these is not recommended as base on groups numbers of labels may change b/w 1-7. So it's better to use Tableview.

Comment: You could replace the first for loop with the zip function to combine the 2 arrays.

Comment: @flanker I didn't know that such a function exist. Thanks as now I know

Comment: @JoakimDanielson To display in labels, a TableView or IBOutletCollection is preferred instead of sttaic 7 labels because now on basis of the grouping number of labels may change.

Answer (score 0):

There are already some decent answers, but reading this it seemed like a functional approach would be a good match for handling the inputs.  This approach uses zip to combine the two datasets into an array of tuples and then reduce to consolidate them, with a bit of pattern matching to mangle the strings into the required shape. Finally it iterates through the resulting array with map to add the consolidated items to the stackviews.

```
let days = ["Monday",
            "Tuesday",
            "Wednesday",
            "Thursday",
            "Friday",
            "Saturday",
            "Sunday"
]

let hours = [
   "00:00-23:59",
   "00:00-23:59",
   "00:00-23:59",
   "00:00-21:59",
   "00:00-22:59",
   "00:00-22:59",
   "00:00-23:59"
]


zip(days, hours)
   .reduce([(String, String)]()){
      guard let last = $0.last else {return [$1]}
      if last.1 == $1.1 {
         var days = last.0
         if let lastDayRange = days.range(of: #"(?<=- )[A-Z,a-z]*day"#, options: .regularExpression) {
            days.replaceSubrange(lastDayRange, with: $1.0)
         } else {
            days = days + " - \($1.0)"
         }
         return $0.dropLast() + [(days, $1.1)]
      } else {
         return $0 + [$1]
      }
   }
   .map{
     let dayLabel = UILabel()
     let hoursLabel = UILabel()   
     dayLabel.text = $0.0
     hoursLabel.text = $0.1
     daysStack.addArrangedSubview(dayLabel) //or whatever the stackview is called
     hoursStack.addArrangedSubview(hoursLabel)
}
```

The UI part is simplistic, and more mght be required to get the desired output, but it should be enough to get started.